# Can I determine the number of actions implied in the actual running transaction?

Tags: transactions, action

transaction_size() returns the size in bytes but is not useful to determine the number of actions implied. Can I get the count?

Comment: maybe [`get_action()`](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/reference#get_action-1) could help?

Comment: not helping :-(, with get_action() I don't know how many actions are running in the transaction